# IF não entrando na condição

Tags: asp.net-mvc, .net

Realizando o debug no código do sistema que estou dando manutenção, porém notei que o "if (_start + 15 >= _count) return;" não permite que o código continue, ele volta no return. Qual seria sugestão para resolver isso?
Já que ele deveria entrar na condição e realizar a paginação, mudando os dados do grid.

```
 case "btnNavNext":
{
var count = 0;
if (_start + 15 >= _count) return;
_currentPage++;
var data = getCaptureValue2(out count, _start + 30, _limit);
StoreSales.PageSize = count;

GridComercio.GetStore().DataSource = data;
GridComercio.GetStore().DataBind();
}
break;
```

Comment: Não temos como saber, existe um contexto enorme que só você sabe. Sem entender completamente o problema, como chega aí, e provavelmente outras informações não tem como ajudarmos, coloque tudo o que é necessário para a pergunta ser reaberta.